# Can't figure out how to display similar field entires

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been learning rails for a while now, but I still have a lot to learn. I recently found this community and I love it.  But now, I am at a loss of what to do.

On the genre/show.html.erb page, I want to display other matching genre.title on this page.

From my understanding I should be able to do this from the show page.

This code of course does not work, and I am sure I am off in the wrong direction, if someone could get me back on path, I would be a happy person.

```
<% if @genre.title == @genre.title %>
  <% @genres.each do |genre| %>
    <%= link_to genre.title, movie_genre_path(@movie, genre) %>

<% end %>
```

This is my route:

```
 movie_genre GET    /movies/:movie_id/genres/:id(.:format)         genres#show
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter your genres in your controller.

```
def show
  movie_genre = Movie.find(params[:movie_id]).genre
  @genres = Genre.where(genre: movie_genre)
end
```

If you use your correct database names in this above code, you will have @genres be what you wanted it to be.